# Is there a specific word for this kind of comparison?

Tags: single-word-requests

"Michael Jordan was to basketball what Messi is to football."

What is the best noun to describe this kind of comparison?

I feel as though I've come across a more specific word than 'metaphor' or 'analogy' in the past, but, I can't think of what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phrased like that, the statement you're making is an *analogy.*

On the other hand, if you rephrase it as *Messi is the MJ of football* or the other way around, you would be using a *metaphor.*

Comment: Analogy certainly seems to be the usual term, in analogy tests but also more generally e.g. https://schott.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/09/11/weekend-competition-a-is-to-b-as-c-is-to-d/